# How to load a HTML in String to WebView in Flutter

Tags: html, string, flutter, webview, webview-flutter

I have some HTML code which is in String variable, not in a file. I want to load this String-HTML on WebView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this package [flutter_html: ^1.0.0](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html#-installing-tab-)

```
import 'package:flutter_html/flutter_html.dart';

SingleChildScrollView(
       child: Html(
               data: "<div></div>", // Your Html code over here
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              ));
```